# Matlab: How to crate a method that loops over Properties whitin a class?

Tags: matlab, class, oop, methods

I wrote a Class called Pokemon and I want to create a loop for a battle between Pokemons.

I am having trouble writing the logic for the winners and loosers of the battle and would appreciate any tips on how to fix what I wrote. Thanks in advance.

**The method should print “I lose” if the first Pokemon (obj) lost to his opponent and “I win” otherwise. The method should also increase the level of the winning Pokemon. The parameter winner should contain the name (not object!) of the winning Pokemon. 
The winner is determined by the following logic: 
Water Pokemons always win Fire Pokemons 
Otherwise – the Pokemon with the higher level wins; and if both Pokemons have the same level, the first Pokemon (obj) wins.**

```
classdef Pokemon

properties (Access = public)
  Type 
  Name 
  Level
end

methods
    function obj = Pokemon(type,name) 

    obj.Type = type;
    obj.Name = name; 
    end

    function speak(obj) 
        disp(obj.Name);
    end

    function obj=increase_level(obj)
        obj.Level = obj.Level + 1;
    end

    function print_level(obj) 
        disp(obj.Level);
    end

    function [obj, opponent, winner] = battle(obj, opponent)
      if obj.Type == PokemonType.Water && opponent.Type == PokemonType.Fire
          winner = obj.Name;
          disp("I win");
          obj.Level = obj.Level + 1; 

      elseif obj.Level >=opponent.Level
          disp("I win");
          winner = obj.Name;
          obj.Level = obj.Level + 1;



     else
         disp("I lose");
         winner = opponent.Name;
         opponent.Level = opponent.Level + 1;

      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have a code to check if what I wrote is right:

```
pikachu = Pokemon(PokemonType.Electric, "Pikachu");
charmander = Pokemon(PokemonType.Fire, "Charmander");
squirtle = Pokemon(PokemonType.Water, "Squirtle");  
pikachu.speak();
charmander.speak();
squirtle.speak();  
pikachu = pikachu.increase_level();
charmander = charmander.increase_level();   % [Now pikachu should have level 1, charmander should have level 1, squirtle should have level 0]
% We expect Pikachu to win - both have the same level, Pikachu is the first
[pikachu, charmander, winner] = pikachu.battle(charmander);
disp(winner);   % [Now pikachu should have level 2, charmander should have level 1, squirtle should have level 0]  
% We expect Squirtle to win - water vs. fire
[charmander, squirtle, winner] = charmander.battle(squirtle);
disp(winner);    % [Now pikachu should have level 2, charmander should have level 1, squirtle should have level 1]  
squirtle = squirtle.increase_level();   % [Now pikachu should have level 2, charmander should have level 1, squirtle should have level 2]  
% We expect squirtle to win - same level
[squirtle, pikachu, winner] = squirtle.battle(pikachu);
disp(winner);
```

I am supposed to get

```
Pikachu 
Charmander 
Squirtle 
I win 
Pikachu 
I lose 
Squirtle 
I win 
Squirtle
```

instead I got:

```
Pikachu
Charmander
Squirtle
I lose
Charmander
I lose
Squirtle
I lose
Pikachu
```

Comment: I just added to the question what is happening. I am not getting the expected output when testing it. maybe I am writing the winning conditions according to the Level wrongly. Would really appreciate any tips. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don’t see where in your code `Level` is first initialized. This might be part of your problem. I would suggest you run your test code in the MATLAB debugger, so that you can examine the values of all the properties at every step, and you can step through the `battle` code to see why it makes the decisions it does. The debugger is really the best way to find errors in logic.